# How to print an html file with textarea in it into another textarea without being parsed by the browser?

Tags: php, html

I want to edit my php or html files on the server without logging in. I wrote a php file to import the file contents that I want to edit. The file contents will be printed in a textarea.

It does work. But, when I import a file with textarea, the browser parses the </textarea> from the file as its end part of the textarea. And the rest parts after  will also be parsed, too.

Is there any methods to prevent the browser from parsing the file?

Answer (score 1):

The HTML inside your textarea needs to use [HTML Entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) instead of the actual symbols. That way it won't be parsed.. so that's something like this:

```
<html> ... </html> <!-- no entities -->

&lt;html&gt; ... &lt;/html&gt; &lt;!-- entities --&gt;
```

I bet there's a lot of functions that can help you with this, like [`htmlentities`()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or some [JavaScript equivalent](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/htmlentities-for-javascript/#:%7E:text=htmlEntities%20for%20JavaScript%20%7C%20CSS%2DTricks&text=htmlentities()%20is%20a%20PHP,a%20native%20version%20of%20it.), that link leads to css-tricks where a really simple JS one is. JS doesn't have a native one, afaik.

Your PHP mustn't be executed, but as [Progman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/286934/progman) stated:

> When the source code is added to the content of the textarea (with
> functions like file_get_contents()), it is not parsed by the PHP
> interpreter. So it is not required to switch to a .html file to
> prevent any PHP executions (there is none).

So, that solves this issue.

Comment: When the source code is added to the content of the textarea (with functions like `file_get_contents()`), it is not parsed by the PHP interpreter. So it is not required to switch to a `.html` file to prevent any PHP executions (there is none).